# Return Json causes save file dialog in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, fullcalendar

I'm integrating jquery fullcalendar into my application.
Here is the code i'm using:

in index.aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
           events: "/Scheduler/CalendarData"
       });
   });  
</script>

<div id="calendar">
</div>
```

Here is the code for Scheduler/CalendarData:

```
public ActionResult CalendarData()
    {

        IList<CalendarDTO> tasksList = new List<CalendarDTO>();

        tasksList.Add(new CalendarDTO
        {
            id = 1,
            title = "Google search",
            start = ToUnixTimespan(DateTime.Now),
            end = ToUnixTimespan(DateTime.Now.AddHours(4)),
            url = "www.google.com"
        });
        tasksList.Add(new CalendarDTO
        {
            id = 1,
            title = "Bing search",
            start = ToUnixTimespan(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)),
            end = ToUnixTimespan(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).AddHours(4)),
            url = "www.bing.com"
        });

        return Json(tasksList,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    private long ToUnixTimespan(DateTime date)
    {
        TimeSpan tspan = date.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(
        new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0));

        return (long)Math.Truncate(tspan.TotalSeconds);
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Index");
    }
```

I also have the following code inside head tag in site.master:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
<link href="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~Perspectiva/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~Perspectiva/Content/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="~Perspectiva/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~Perspectiva/Scripts/fullcalendar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Everything I did was pretty much copied from http://szahariev.blogspot.com/2009/08/jquery-fullcalendar-and-aspnet-mvc.html

When navigating to /scheduler/calendardata I get a prompt for saving the json data which contents are exactly what I created in the CalendarData function.

What do I need to do in order to render the page correctly?

Thanks in advance,

Eran

**Update:**  Following Rune's and Franci's comments I added a view called CalendarData.aspx which is identical to index.aspx. Results:

- Navigating to /scheduler/calendardata
  still gives me the save file dialog.
- Navigating to /scheduler/index I get
  the following runtime error in Visual
  Studio:  Microsoft JScript runtime
  error: Object expected.  VS
  highlights the
  $(document).ready(function()...) 
  code in the scrip tag.

Comment: If you haven't altered anything else, adding the CalendarData.aspx view will not change anything, since no action is returning that view.
What you are seeing when navigating to /scheduler/index is probably the correct page, but it has a javascript error in it. It seems that your ASP.NET MVC stuff (views and actions) is now correct, but there's a problem with the javascript. Try accessing /scheduler/index using FireFox or Chrome and investigate the js bug further, possibly using the FireBug-plugin for FireFox

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed? I am having this issue now and can't seem to overcome it.

Comment: It's been a while since I've touched this code, but if I remember correctly the solution was placing all the links to the css and js files in the aspx file instead of the master page and using Url.Content() to encode them.  Hope This Helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try using a JSonResult instead of an ActionResult.

```
public JSonResult CalendarData()
{
    IList<CalendarDTO> tasksList = new List<CalendarDTO>();

    tasksList.Add(new CalendarDTO
    {
        id = 1,
        title = "Google search",
        start = ToUnixTimespan(DateTime.Now),
        end = ToUnixTimespan(DateTime.Now.AddHours(4)),
        url = "www.google.com"
    });
    tasksList.Add(new CalendarDTO
    {
        id = 1,
        title = "Bing search",
        start = ToUnixTimespan(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)),
        end = ToUnixTimespan(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).AddHours(4)),
        url = "www.bing.com"
    });

    return Json(tasksList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to navigate to the URL mapped to an action returning Index.aspx instead of the URL mapped to CalendarData(). I assume this would be something like "/scheduler". When you go to "/scheduler/calenderData" the server will return the Json data straight to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to `/scheduler/calendarData` in the browser, the browser gets a response with `Content-Type: application/json`. Some browsers don't know how to display such content type, so they let you save the content as a local file, so you could view it in another program.

You should be navigating to your browser to `/scheduler/index` instead, which returns a human-readable result that can be rendered by all browsers (has `Content-Type: text/html`).

If you want to see the content returned by `CalendarData` for debugging purposes, you have two options:

- use browser that understands `Content-Type: application/json`
- use a tool like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com), that allows you to inspect the HTTP traffic

Answer (score 0):

Try using a JSonResult instead of an ActionResult.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and I was missing the basic ActionResult that returned the View to start with...? I was thinking it was something deeper...but here is the basic things to check that fixed my issue;

in my Homecontroller;

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Whatever!!! just work!";

        return View();
    }
```

in Global, I also had to refix my maproutes back to default as I was roting to the GetData action when try things to fix it:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                              // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have gotten this to work without having the end user go through crazy stuff is to change the content type to "text/html" in the return.

I have tried all the suggestions above, as well as a few other.

Heck, I even tried [this](http://leftend.com/Blog/Stop-IE-From-Displaying-a-File-Download-dialog-when-returning-JSON).